# Can I have a table layout with doxygen's @return command?

Tags: doxygen

Is it possible to have some form of table layout in the output of doxygen's `@return` command?

```
/**
 * @return error code,
 *         @ref E_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER_SIZE if @c bufsize is too small,
 *         @ref E_INSUFFICIENT_ARRAY_SIZE  if @c arrsize is too small
 */
```

is displayed in the HTML output as one line:

> error code, E_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER_SIZE if bufsize is too small, E_INSUFFICIENT_ARRAY_SIZE if arrsize is too small

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution could lie in the usage of a dash.

```
/**
 * @return error code,
 *        - @ref E_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER_SIZE if @c bufsize is too small,
 *        - @ref E_INSUFFICIENT_ARRAY_SIZE  if @c arrsize is too small
 */
```